# database tranactions in django for dependent operations

Tags: python, django, transactions

I am new to Django and have some model definitions as follows:

```
class ProjectModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "projects"

class StudyModel(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(ProjectModel)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "studies"
```

I have an associated view which allows the user to create a project and a study at the same time. I do it as follows:

```
pid = ProjectModel.objects.filter(name__iexact=project_name).first()
    if pid is None:
        try:
            #with transaction.atomic():
            pobj = ProjectModel.objects.create(name="A", description="")
            sobj = StudyModel.objects.create(name="B", description="", project_id=pobj.pk)

            except:
                #pobj.delete()
                #sobj.delete()
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_417_EXPECTATION_FAILED)
```

I have been thinking about how to do this so that if any of the operations fail, the database stays untouched i.e. if the `study` is not created for some reason, the `project` is not created either.

One way i thought it is doable is to mark the method `savepoints` before calling the `objects.create` and then rolling back in the exception handler. However, I am not sure if that is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) (like you have commented out) to wrap operations into single, database transaction.

```
from django.db import DatabaseError, transaction

if pid is None:
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            pobj = ProjectModel.objects.create(name="A", description="")
            sobj = StudyModel.objects.create(name="B", description="", project_id=pobj.pk)
    except DatabaseError:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_417_EXPECTATION_FAILED)
```

Comment: ok, so I guess I do not have to worry about unrolling.... This was giving errors before but I realized it was coming from another source...